# Bootstrap, how can I use two data-toggle in the same href?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, href

I want to use both a tooltip and a modal in the same href, but they are both activated using the data-toggle attribute in the href.

Can I have them run both?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. Based on the bootstrap default ID names

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top" id="example">Tooltip on top</a>

<script>
 $('#example').tooltip();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This should do it for you. Based on the bootstrap default ID names

`<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top" id="example">Tooltip on top</a>`

`<script>
 $('#example').tooltip();
</script>`

The previous answer from Matt worked for me but make sure you don't leave title blank.  Put your tooltip text here:

`title="Tooltip text"`